# Spam false positive due to ad related example links in a question

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, spam

Does anyone think that this question being used for a review is getting picked up as spam because of the example links that the OP uses, which happen to be ads?

It seems that those example links, while they are ads, do legitimately show what the OP is trying to accomplish. They may be working on an advertising site, if I'm reading their post on the CDN correctly.

I agree that the OP is asking a poorly researched question. I believe it definitely requires editing. I could even support this as being closed as off-topic because we aren't Pinterest support. But do we really consider this spam, and if so, why?

[Audit Result](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10306327)

> Title: Pinterest sharing issue 
>   I'm dabbling in Pinterest for a first time and having issues with the titles that are pulling through when pages/images are shared.
>   Here's a version of the site for reference:
>   http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/advertisingcdn/GoodFoodHtmlAd/baileys/index.html
>
> At present, although the pages and images can be successfully shared
>   on Pinterest boards, the titles are listed incorrectly even though
>   they are correct within the page's schema meta data. Bizarrely they
>   also appear to be correct when checked via Pinterest's own validator.
>
> See https://www.pinterest.com/gavindayjohn/comp-test/ for an example
>   of how they are displaying in Pinterest.
>
> Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is another reason why users should be providing MCVEs (and screenshots when it makes sense to) instead of linking directly to sites.

Comment: Yup, no question @BSMP users are not providing the smallest possible example if they only link things. The purpose of my question is to ask if we flag links to example sites, that just so happen to be ads, as spam when they really are not.

Comment: The review audit process is clearly broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's in the audit queue because it was (presumably) flagged as spam, then deleted by a moderator. I think the only way to remove it from the queue now is to undelete it. It probably would be better to undelete this example and close it for not posting code in the question itself. (Since it's only a few days old, the OP might come back and fix it. If it were much older, I'd say just leave it deleted.)

That being said, these types of questions do need to be shut down quickly, whether they really are spam or not. If you leave a gap where people are allowed to post links to advertisements in questions, you can guess what will fill that gap in short order.

Comment: Yeah, it had a validated spam flag on it when it was deleted, which is what triggered the use as an audit case. I don't think it was actual spam, so I've cleared the spam flag and re-deleted the post.

Comment: @BradLarson thank you for following up on that. Since it is no longer flagged as spam, is it possible to remove the failed audit from my profile? No pressure if that's too much work though.

Comment: @JasonD - We can't remove the audit failure from the system, but I can lift the review ban, so I've done that.

Comment: Thank you @BradLarson appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to argue that it is spam. Why?

A legit question doesn't need to contain any advertising material. Create a MCVE, blur/blackout company name/logos in screenshots, change text to something generic in the code. It might be easier to leave it in but it does not break the question to take it out.

Just because the question itself may be legit doesn't make the ad link/image/text not spam.

Comment: This might not be possible e.g. when talking about a URL that is supposed to be caught by a spam filter that you wrote.